# Click Targets Expanded on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am creating an off-canvas navigation menu and have found an issue on two Nexus devices, on Chrome only. I am using the latest version.

Elements which have click events assigned to them, including native anchor tags, respond to touches outside of their confines, by what feels like 5–10px.

Is there any information about this behaviour and is there anyway to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be replicated on chrome on nexus devices, with this fiddle (prepared by the OP)

```
<style>
#button { margin: 50px auto; background-color: teal; color: white; width: 200px; line-height: 50px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; font-family: sans-serif; -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; user-select: none; }
</style>

<body>
<div id="button">Touch/Click this button</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        alert('document touch target: ' + event.target);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GZbZv/

Tap *near* the button, you can actually tap outside of it on a nexus and still get a hit.

Comment: This seems to be an issue in Chrome. Assigning click event to elements enlarge their click target area by 12px https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=530725&q=label%3ACr-Blink-Input&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified